# H256 to_string() function does not return complete string

Tags: extrinsic, hash, string

I have a H256 value which is an extrinsic returned hash

`0x8d19a2e575d583b8812418c71be304f16a978cfac2bfad54afcad824cb4d3471`

but when i convert this to String using `.to_string()`

it does not return complete string

`0x8d19…3471`

Answer (score 3):

To convert it to string we can use format macro instead

`let tx_hash = format!("{:?}", h256_object);`